# How to customize Log4j properties file in YARN

Tags: logging, apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn

I am running an application on top of YARN in spark cluster but I need to set my own path where log files are created and need to change the formatting of log message. For this I want to use my customized Log4j.properties file instead of the default log4j.properties file provided by YARN. How can this be done?

Comment: Add the `log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/application.log` property in log4j file and check.

Comment: This will not solve my problem as by making modifications in default log4j.properties file, log files of other applications will also get impacted since they will be referring to the default .properties file. Instead, I want to use my own customized .properties file and use it in few specific applications. How can this be done?

Comment: Create your own log4j property file and add property file in your spark class path.

Answer (score 1):

I use this spark-submit script to push my `log4j.properties` up to Yarn so that I can control the logging pattern. I particularly wanted the full package names so I can grep out what my classes where logging, from the resulting Yarn application logs.

```
spark-submit \
    --class com.acme.Main \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 2g \
    --executor-memory 1g \
    --driver-class-path "./conf" \
    --files "./conf/app.properties,./conf/log4j.properties" \
    ./lib/my-app-uber.jar \
    "$@"
```

Personally I only use the `ConsoleAppender` and all my application logging appears in the standard Yarn logs along with everything else. You can't use the `RollingFileAppender` with HDFS.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %-5p %c:%L -> %m%n
```

You should see your results in

```
yarn logs -applicationId <your-app-id>
```